# Как ускорить процесс поиска?

Tags: python, api

Я использую iTunes Store API, в котором я могу выполнять поиск. Например, я ввожу название книги и у меня есть вся информация про нее. Но мне надо все книги, которые есть в базе данных iTunes. Вот мой код, он ищет ID книг. Он работает, но очень медленно и не эффективно. Посоветуйте, как улучшить его работу.

```
import random
import time
import itunespy
def lookup_id():
    books = []
    for j in range(1000):
        i = random.randint(100000000,10000000000)
        try:
            lookup = itunespy.lookup_book(id=i)
            books.append(lookup)
            print(lookup)
        except LookupError:
            print('d')
        except ConnectionError:
            print("ZZzzzz...")
            time.sleep(5)
    print(books)

lookup_id()
```

Comment: Производительность упирается в запросы по сети, тут мало что можно сделать

Comment: Вы точно уверены что в API нет методов для поиска книги? И на крайняк можно спарсить веб-форму поиска